# Meshcat fails to import PNG for Cracker Box in Drake Planar Force Control Demo

Tags: drake

I tried to adapt/rewrite the [force control demo](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Manipulation-ac8201a1-470a-4c77-afd0-2cc45bc229ff/project/7-Force-Control-87d8044f-3eb2-4f25-b52f-f51a5eca68b7/%2Fforce.ipynb) with a locally `pip` installed version of pydrake (v1.8.0). The cracker box texture doesn't seem to load (box shows up white), and it produces errors like:

```
WARNING:drake:Ignoring Meshcat http request for /003_cracker_box_textured.png
```

The `sdf` loads fine. It points to an `obj`, which points to an `mtl`, which points to a `png`. All of these exist in `.../site-packages/pydrake/share/drake/manipulation/models/ycb/meshes`.

Do I need to move the meshes to somewhere else?

Mininum repro script:

```
from pydrake.common import FindResourceOrThrow
from pydrake.systems.framework import DiagramBuilder
from pydrake.multibody.parsing import Parser
from pydrake.multibody.plant import AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph
from pydrake.multibody.meshcat import JointSliders
from pydrake.math import RigidTransform
from pydrake.geometry import StartMeshcat, MeshcatVisualizer


meshcat = StartMeshcat()

builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.005)
parser = Parser(plant)

box = parser.AddModelFromFile(FindResourceOrThrow('drake/manipulation/models/ycb/sdf/003_cracker_box.sdf'))
    
plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), 
                plant.GetFrameByName("base_link_cracker", box),
                RigidTransform.Identity())

plant.Finalize()

MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
sliders = builder.AddSystem(JointSliders(meshcat, plant))
diagram = builder.Build()
sliders.Run(diagram, None)

input('press any key to stop...')
```

Relevant part of the `003_cracker_box_textured.obj` file:

```
# Generated by Katamari OBJ encoder.
# Vertices: 8194
# Faces: 16384
mtllib 003_cracker_box_textured.mtl
v -0.046666 -0.079014 0.089823
v -0.046390 -0.081674 0.083110
v -0.045613 -0.091869 0.086920
... <more geometric features for the rest of the file>
```

Entire `003_cracker_box_textured.mtl` file:

```
newmtl material_0
# shader_type beckmann
map_Kd 003_cracker_box_textured.png
```

Comment: My answer is born of ignorance. But the path `/003_cracker_box_textured.png` worries me. That makes it look like there's an absolute path at the root of your drive.

What does the content of the .mtl file look like? Does it refer to `map_Kd /003_cracker_box_textured.png`?

Comment: That's an http path.  It means that meshcat.js is http requesing that png file from the root of the web server.  Since we just dump objs unchanged over to meshcat.js, it presumably thinks it can load the texture from the root.

Comment: I made and edit with the contents of the `obj` and `mtl` files. Should I edit the path in the `mtl` file with a longer `relative` path? If so, relative to `pydrake` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Does it also produce an error like "Meshcat: Failed to load texture. AAAA references BBBB, but Meshcat could not open filename CCCC"?

If so, then the problem is simply that `pip install drake` doesn't include the ycb texture files in that distribution channel (because it would make the wheels too bit for pypi).

See https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html which says "Drake’s support for pip has a few known issues (see issue [#15954](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/15954))" which links to [#15774](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/15774).  Once the wheels have this data (either in a different wheel file, or downloaded on demand), that issue will be closed.

In the meantime, as a work-around you could try one of the other https://drake.mit.edu/installation.html methods such as Apt, Tgz, or Docker.  The Wheel is the only installation method that does not include texture files.

Though I'm confused because you said you used `pip` but somehow you do have the `obj` and `mtl` files?

Comment: I think a couple days ago I might've gotten that kind of error and copied the mtl/obj files into where the errors indicated they were looking. That seemed to work fine for the shapes, but not the textures. Is there some way to edit the sdf/obj/mtl to get it to point to the right files? I assume the pip installation still allows me to use my own obj/mtl/png files right?

Comment: A triad of {mtl, obj, png} files should all live in same directory, and the filenames within them such as `mtllib 003_cracker_box_textured.mtl` and `map_Kd 003_cracker_box_textured.png` should not have any pathname characters (`/`).